# Rating changes and probability calculations for chess world championship

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I have some interesting questions that have to do with the rating changes and calculations for the Anand-Carlsen world championship. Most of this has to do with solving a system of linear equations.

First, some preliminary information:

Carlsen's live rating: **2870**, Anand's live rating: **2775**

If Carlsen wins a game, he gains **3.7 points**; draw **-1.3 points**, loss **-6.3 points**.

If Anand wins a game, he gains **6.3 points**; draw **1.3 points**, loss **-3.7 points**.

The match will be 12 games, with **WIN=1 point, DRAW=0.5 points, LOSS=0 points** with the winner being the first to 6 points. Therefore, **the number of standard rated games in the match can vary** based on all the **ordered** possibilities of wins, draws, and losses.

My questions are:

**1. What are the possibilities for Carlsen to cross 2900 in live rating?**

**2. What are the possibilities for Anand to cross 2800 in live rating?**

**3. What are the upper and lower bounds for Carlsen's rating in the match, given the stipulations?**

**4. What are the upper and lower bounds for Anand's rating in the match, given the stipulations?**

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might find it interesting: http://chessbase.com/Home/TabId/211/PostId/4011007/are-the-chess-world-champions-just-lucky--part-2-060913.aspx

Comment: Yup thanks, have read it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

What is the maximum number of points that Carlsen can gain?  That makes 1 easy

For 2, you need to list the cases.  Order does not matter, just the number of wins, losses, and draws.  Note that a player can score 6.5 if he has 5.5 and wins the last game.

For 3 upside, only one result increases Carlsen's rating.  How many games can he win?  For the downside, note that two draws give Anand a point, as does a loss, but the loss hurts more.

4 is like 3, upside down.

Comment: Ok. I calculated that two draws equals one win and one loss, **both** in match points and rating gains. Therefore, all the possibilities of a tied match after 12 games result in +15.6 rating gain. Is there a way to set up a linear system to calculate for a 6.5-5.5 match scenario, and 7-5, 7.5-4.5 etc.?

Comment: There is no 7.5-4.5 match, because they stop when one player gets 6.5 (or both have 6).  There are only matches that end at 6-6, 6.5 to something with a half or 7 to something without a half.  There are not many possibilities, so I would just list them.  Yes, you can set an equation that if Carlsen wins 7 to x, his rating gain is $7 \cdot 6.3 - 3.7 \cdot x$, but I don't think it saves any work.

Comment: Also, Carlsen's maximum rating, 2895.9, is attained if he wins 7-0, and thus Anand's minimum rating, 2749.1. Anand's maximum rating, 2819.1, is attained if he wins 7-0, and thus Carlsen's minimum rating 2825.9.

Comment: So # 1,3, and 4 are taken care of. I just need to solve #2.

Comment: Should've thought it would be 6-0 in each case

Comment: Oh I see now Carlsen can have more than 6 wins

Comment: After $6-0$, there will be still be at least one more game played, because there is a possibility of the other player scoring a point to stay "alive". But, if the first player scores the point on the $7th$ game, then he wins the match $7-0$.

Comment: And if the other player wins a point to stay alive,does the player with 6 wins still only need one more win to win? Taking into account the new info you've provided, in certain cases, if not all cases, the winner is not the first player to 6 points, but the first player to 7.

Comment: Yes, the first that gets to 6.5 (or 7) wins.  It is a tie (and the title stays with the current holder) if it gets to 6-6.

Comment: 6.5 or 7 match points that is, since 6.5 match points can be reached with 5 wins and 3 draws...

Comment: or 4 wins and 5 draws

Comment: or 3 wins and 7 draws or 2 wins and 9 draws or 1 win and 11 draws

Comment: What happens if its reaches 5-3, then 6-3? Does it stop there or must the player with 6 the another win/draw to win the match? I assumes they must i.e. winner is first to 6.5/7 match points as you've said.

Comment: Yes, at 6-3 they keep playing, even at 6-5, regardless of how they got there

Comment: They keep playing, but do they still stop at 6.5 or 7 match points regardless of how they got to 6-3 or 6-5? I think yes, but just trying to nail it.

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

The answer for $1$ is NEVER, because even if Carlsen has the theoretically best possible tournament with $7-0$, his rating would go to $2895.9$ only.

The answer for $2$ is if:

```
Anand wins the match $7-0$, making his rating $2819.1$
```

OR

```
Anand wins the match $6.5-5.5$ (order of game results does not matter) by:

6 wins, 1 draw in a 7-game match: new rating = 2814.1
5 wins, 3 draws in a 8-game match: new rating = 2810.4
4 wins, 5 draws in a 9-game match: new rating = 2806.7
3 wins, 7 draws in a 10-game match. new rating = 2803.0
```

The answers for $3$ and $4$ are:

Carlsen's maximum rating, $2895.9$, is attained if he wins $7-0$, and thus Anand's minimum rating, $2749.1$. Anand's maximum rating, $2819.1$, is attained if he wins $7-0$, and thus Carlsen's minimum rating $2825.9$.

Comment: For part 2, what about 2 draws followed by 6 wins and the other 16 possibilities which take Anand's rating over 2800 I've put on my answer which aren't on yours?  For part 4, it seems to me that Anand's maximum rating is achieved by 2 draws and then 6 wins rather than 6 wins and then 1 draw.

Comment: No your 4 is right, it's just 2 I disagree with: it seems to me that there are actually 17 possibilities which take Anand's rating over 2800 which aren't on your answer rather than 16 as I said in my last comment (see my answer for a list of them).

Comment: Actually it's 9 possibilities I see for Anand' rating to go over 2800 which aren't on your answer (see my answer for details).

Comment: Actually: my answer was wrong: I've just reedited it.  There were only 5 possibilites not mentioned on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've sorted 1, 3 and 4. Here's part 2, which I've just trawled through:

Assuming that the match stops when one players gets 6.5 or more match points, the possibilities which take Anand's rating above 2800 are as follows:

0 D and 7 W  (new rating of 2819.1)

1 D and 6 W  (new rating of 2814.1)

2 D and 6 W  (new rating of 2815.4)

3 D and 5 W

4 D and 5 W

5 D and 4 W

6 D and 4 W

7 D and 3 W

8 D and 3 W

10 D and 2 W